# ModuleNotFoundError TA-Lib in Heroku

Tags: python-3.x, heroku, web-deployment, modulenotfounderror, ta-lib

I have been trying to deploy an app that uses the library [TA-lib](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#ta-lib) in Heroku, however, I keep getting a ModuleNotFoundError, even though I had put in `requirements.txt` the library `TA-Lib` and also tried to put the .whl file in the `requirements.txt`

```
TA_Lib-0.4.17-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl #I am using Python 3.6.13 in Heroku server
streamlit==0.49.0
altair==3.2.0
sklearn
pandas
numpy
plotly
matplotlib
seaborn
IPython
tqdm
alpha_vantage
xgboost
yfinance
lxml
```

Is there another way to install the .whl file in the server?

Comment: TA-Lib is a C library. You are installing a python wrapper for it. It won't install if C library isn't on server already. So you need to install a TA-Lib binary first, then install python modules. Check out this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43453953/how-to-install-python-library-in-heroku

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment section by truf - my problem was in installing TA-Lib first. So, in the section to add for buildpacks in Heroku, I added https://github.com/aneesh-neelam/heroku-buildpack-python-talib. This way, I could properly run the server.